# How to set connection timeout with OAuth2RestTemplate while fetching access token

Tags: spring-oauth2

We are able to fetch access token using attached code snapshot but didn't find any way to set connection timeout as we do with spring restTemplate.Is there any way to set a connection timeout with OAuth2RestTemplate.

```
<bean id="bean" class="com.test.Provider">
            <constructor-arg name="context" ref="context" />
            <constructor-arg name="detail" ref="resourceDetails" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="context" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.DefaultOAuth2ClientContext">
            <constructor-arg name="accessTokenRequest" ref="request" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="request" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.DefaultAccessTokenRequest"/>

        <bean id="resourceDetails" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.client.ClientCredentialsResourceDetails"/>
```

Comment: and to fetch token at java side tokenString = new OAuth2RestTemplate(this.resourceDetails, this.context).getAccessToken().getValue();

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party, but in case you're wondering how to do this with springboot, this is a way:

```java
    @Bean
    protected OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate(ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory) {
        OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(oAuthDetails());
        oAuth2RestTemplate.setRequestFactory(clientHttpRequestFactory);
        return oAuth2RestTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    protected ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory() {
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(10000); //timeout in milliseconds
        requestFactory.setReadTimeout(10000); //timeout in milliseconds
        return requestFactory;
    }
```

Where `oAuthDetails()` is a method that reads the oauth configuration properties, similar to this:

```java
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("path.to.your.oauth.properties.on.yml")
    protected ClientCredentialsResourceDetails oAuthDetails() {
        return new ClientCredentialsResourceDetails();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right, the way you give the connection timeout to the Spring RestTemplate as a constructor argument is through giving a ClientHttpRequestFactory as an argument to the constructor

```
RestTemplate(ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory)
```

Using for example the HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory, one can set the connection timeout to the RestClient in XML as follows

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
  <constructor-arg name="requestFactory">
    <bean id="requestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
      <property name="connectTimeout" value="2000" />
      <property name="readTimeout" value="10000" />
    </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

RestTemplate also offers a way to set the requestFactory property through a setter, which it inherits from InterceptingHttpAccessor, and in fact the constructor itself seems to use that setter to set the requestFactory given as constructor argument.

Thus, you can set the requestFactory for the OAuth2RestTemplate through the setter. In XML:

```
<bean id="oauth2RestTemplate" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate">
  <constructor-arg name="resource" ref="resourceDetails" />
  <constructor-arg name="context" ref="context" />
  <property name="requestFactory">
    <bean id="requestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
      <property name="connectTimeout" value="2000" />
      <property name="readTimeout" value="10000" />
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

Or, in your case, you can for example give your class com.test.Provider a constructor argument requestFactory and then use that to set the request factory in the OAuth2RestTemplate as follows:

XML:

```
<bean id="bean" class="com.test.Provider">
  <constructor-arg name="context" ref="context" />
  <constructor-arg name="resourceDetails" ref="resourceDetails" />
  <constructor-arg name="requestFactory">
    <bean id="requestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
      <property name="connectTimeout" value="2000" />
      <property name="readTimeout" value="10000" />
    </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

And in your code set

```
OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(this.resourceDetails, this.context);
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(this.requestFactory);
String tokenString = restTemplate.getAccessToken().getValue();
```

after setting the value of this.requestFactory in the constructor.

PS. I would prefer to create a single OAuth2RestTemplate for the entire class as a private field and reuse it in that class, unless you have a reason to create a new one for each request. You could create it in the constructor, as you are giving the context and details as constructor arguments, or then in a post-construct/init-method. Or even give it as a constructor-argument or as a property to your class in the XML, in case the context and resourceDetails are not used outside the restTemplate.

## EDIT

After doing some more research, it seems that the problem might be harder than I thought. OAuth2RestTemplate uses an AccessTokenProvider to get the access tokens, by default it uses a chain of AccessTokenProviders through a instance of AccessTokenProviderChain in order to support the different types of grant types. It seems that each of these uses their own RestTemplate to send the requests to obtain the access token. Unfortunately, it seems that OAuth2RestTemplate doesn't offer a simple way to set the requestFactory of the default AccessTokenProviders' restTemplates.

So, if the solution that I proposed above is not working (which I suspect), I would use the following approach which I believe to work.

All the default AccessTokenProviders in Spring Security Oauth2 extend the class OAuth2AccessTokenSupport, which also is the class that creates the internal RestTemplate. Fortunately, this class offers a setter to set the requestFactory of the internal RestTemplate. So, one can create for example an instance of a ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider and give set the requestFactory through the setRequestFactory(...) method. In XML:

```
<bean id="clientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.client.ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider">
  <property name="requestFactory">
    <bean id="requestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
      <property name="connectTimeout" value="2000" />
      <property name="readTimeout" value="10000" />
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

For some reason the OAuth2RestTemplate doesn't offer a way to access the default AccessTokenProviders, but one can set them through the setAccessTokenProvider(AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider) setter. To replicate the original default behaviour of the OAuth2RestTemplate, one would have to give an instance of a AccessTokenProviderChain, together with four default AccessTokenProviders and set their requestFactories. However, as you know that the accessed resource is of type ClientCredentialsResourceDetails, it suffices to set a single ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider in the setAccessTokenProvider(...) setter and set the requestFactory of the ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider.

So we would get the following code:

XML:

```
<bean id="bean" class="com.test.Provider">
  <constructor-arg name="context" ref="context" />
  <constructor-arg name="resourceDetails" ref="resourceDetails" />
  <constructor-arg name="accessTokenProvider" ref="clientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.client.ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider">
  <property name="requestFactory">
    <bean id="requestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
      <property name="connectTimeout" value="2000" />
      <property name="readTimeout" value="10000" />
    </bean>
  </property>
</bean>
```

And in your code, set the AccessTokenProvider:

```
OAuth2RestTemplate restTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(this.resourceDetails, this.context);
restTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(this.accessTokenProvider);
String tokenString = restTemplate.getAccessToken().getValue();
```

after setting the value of this.accessTokenProvider in the constructor. If you decide to create the OAuth2RestTemplate in the XML, you can write

```
<bean id="oauth2RestTemplate" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate">
  <constructor-arg name="resource" ref="resourceDetails" />
  <constructor-arg name="context" ref="context" />
  <property name="accessTokenProvider" ref="clientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider" />
</bean>
```

where the bean "clientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider" is defined as above.

Hope that this works.

Answer (score 0):

One issue with above solution is that `ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider` uses a bit enhanced requestFactory:

```java
private ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory() {
    protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) throws IOException {
        super.prepareConnection(connection, httpMethod);
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        ...
    }

    ...
};
```

So in order to preserve the original functionality you should set up the same implementation of the factory.